# How to seed with relationships in Prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I'm playing around with seeding in Prisma and I'm struggling to find examples that aren't super basic. In the example below, I want to create a `User` (author) who has authored multiple `Services` (1:n) and each `Service` has can come from one `Provider`.

- `User` - 1:n - `Services`
- `Services` m:1 - `Provider`

In the example below, the creation process results in 3 instances of "AWS" on the `Provider` table. Which, makes sense given the syntax used. I'd like to just have one **Record** of AWS, GCP, and AZURE (my provider enums) respectively.

Also, if anyone has a more eloquent example of how to generate this to be more scalable of a seed please let me know.

#### seed.ts

```js
const main = async () => {
  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "moderator@gmail.com",
      username: "timothy",
      role: "MODERATOR",
      authored: {
        create: [
          {
            name: "Simple Storage Service",
            acronym: "S3",
            provider: {
              create: {
                name: "AWS", // how can these all reference the same Provider table row?
              },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "DynamoDB",
            acronym: "DynamoDB",
            provider: {
              create: {
                name: "AWS",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "API Gateway",
            acronym: "API Gateway",
            provider: {
              create: {
                name: "AWS",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "BigQuery",
            acronym: "BigQuery",
            provider: {
              create: {
                name: "GCP",
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
};
```

#### schema.prisma

```
enum Providers {
  AWS
  GCP
  AZURE
}

enum Role {
  USER
  MODERATOR
  ADMIN
}

model User {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  username  String    @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  role      Role      @default(USER)
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  authored  Service[]
}

model Service {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String   @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  acronym    String   @unique @db.VarChar(255)
  authorId   Int
  providerId Int
  author     User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  provider   Provider @relation(fields: [providerId], references: [id])
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Provider {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      Providers
  Services  Service[]
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
}
```

Current result in the `Provider`'s table. There should not be duplicates (triplicates) of "AWS".

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just precreate provider and then `connect` it to the service:

```
const main = async () => {
  const awsProvider = await prisma.providers.create({
    data: { name: 'AWS' }
  })

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "moderator@gmail.com",
      username: "timothy",
      role: "MODERATOR",
      authored: {
        create: [
          {
            name: "Simple Storage Service",
            acronym: "S3",
            provider: {
              connect: awsProvider
            },
          },

// ...
```

Comment: It's almost working, currently troubleshooting the current error when I try to use your example and seed:  Unknown arg `createdAt` in data.authored.create.2.provider.connect.createdAt for type ProviderWhereUniqueInput. Available args: type ProviderWhereUniqueInput {id?: Int}. I tried using `awsProvider.id` but it didn't like that. hmm.

Comment: when I use: `awsProvider.id` the following error returns: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ProviderWhereUniqueInput | undefined'.

Comment: I've resolved this issue and created a new answer below. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved the issue, the example below shows how to *connect* or associate the tables in the seed.

here are the relevant [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries).

```js
const main = async () => {
  const awsProvider = await prisma.provider.create({
    data: { name: "AWS" },
  });
  const gcpProvider = await prisma.provider.create({
    data: { name: "GCP" },
  });

  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      email: "moderator@gmail.com",
      username: "timothy",
      role: "MODERATOR",
      authored: {
        create: [
          {
            name: "Simple Storage Service",
            acronym: "S3",
            provider: {
              connect: { id: awsProvider.id },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "DynamoDB",
            acronym: "DynamoDB",
            provider: {
              connect: { id: awsProvider.id },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "API Gateway",
            acronym: "API Gateway",
            provider: {
              connect: { id: awsProvider.id },
            },
          },
          {
            name: "BigQuery",
            acronym: "BigQuery",
            provider: {
              connect: { id: gcpProvider.id },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
};
```